# Multiple ImageView with Audio Files

Tags: android

I have 25 Images inside a Grid layout, now I want to link each image by its audio files (almost 15 sec each audio file), example Image1 plays Audio1, but at the same time if the user clicks other Images, the Audio1 stops and plays the current Image which was clicked.
So Image1 click Audio1 plays, and if Image(X) clicked Audio1 stops and Audio(X) plays.
I know the codes that I used is terrible. Sorry
Any help would be appreciated

```
    let_a = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.let_a);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.wl_a);

    let_b = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.let_b);
    final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.wl_b);

    let_c = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.let_c);
    final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.wl_c);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Better Approach would be `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` Learn it [here](https://www.codingdemos.com/android-gridlayout-example-recyclerview/)

However, in your code
You can have one MediaPlayer object instead of 25

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
```

inside `onClickListener` of your ImageView

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    mp.stop();
                }
                mp.release();
                mp =  MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.file_name);
                mp.start();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should create only one object of MediaPlayer class.

```
MediaPlayer mp;
```

Make a function in your Activity or Fragment which ever you are using.

```
private void playSound(int soundId) {
    if(mp != null){
       mp.release();
       mp = null;
    }
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, soundId);
    mp.start();
}
```

And, you can call above function like this.

```
let_a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playSound(R.raw.wl_a);
            }
        });
let_b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playSound(R.raw.wl_b);
            }
        });
```

Hope it helps.